# why can't I cast a pointer to Derived class member function to the same but of class Base?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

To me it looks perfectly safe to cast a `void(Derived::*)()` to a `void(Base::*)()`, like in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
struct Base{
    void(Base::*any_method)();
    void call_it(){
        (this->*any_method)();
    }
};
struct Derived: public Base{
    void a_method(){
        cout<<"method!"<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    Base& a=*new Derived;
    a.any_method=&Derived::a_method;
    a.call_it();
}
```

But the compiler complains about the cast at `a.any_method=&Derived::a_method;`. Is this a roadblock to prevent subtle programming errors, or just something to make life easier for compiler writers? Are there workarounds to let the `Base` class have a pointer to member functions of `Derived` *without type knoweledge* (that is, I cannot make `Base` a template with template argument `Derived`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens if your `Derived::a_method()` attempts to use a data member only present in `Derived`, not in `Base`, and you call it on a `Base` object (or an object derived from `Base` but not related to `Derived`)?

The conversion the other way around makes sense, this one doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's potentially dangerous.

A derived class function can use all the derived class properties of `*this`. A pointer to base class function can be called on any base class instance, even those that are not of the derived type.

Accessing the derived class properties of an instance that isn't a derived class isn't going to work so casting a pointer to derived class function to a pointer to base class pointer is correctly not allowed.

On the other hand, casting a pointer to base class function to a pointer to derived class function is safe and legal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `std::function<void()>`. This can be any member of any class, a lambda, a free function, a function object, whatever you need, which is super convenient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
struct Base{
    std::function<void()> any_method;
    void call_it(){
        any_method();
    }
};
struct Derived: public Base{
    void a_method(){
        cout<<"method!"<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    Derived* d = new Derived;
    Base& a= *d;
    a.any_method = [d] { d->a_method(); };
    a.call_it();
}
```

Here you can see that the actual implementation of `any_method` is *totally* abstracted from `struct Base`, and I can supply a function object that does anything, at all- including conveniently calling a Derived method.

Comment: It's not very clear how `std::function` can help here: `std::function<void(Base::*)>` has the same problem and if one renounces to give `any_method` the type of member function, then there's no point to use `std::function` at all instead of a plain free function pointer. Right?

Comment: @Lorenzo: No. `std::function<void()>`. The function can store it's own `this` pointer. In addition, there is always a point to `std::function` over a function pointer- stateful lambdas, the result of `std::bind`, for example. I edited my answer to make it more obvious how `std::function` instantaneously solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this can be somewhat surprising. However it makes sense if you think about it.

For a cast between two types to be automatic, the following relation should hold: any instance of the first type should be representable in the second.

For example, if `d` is an instance of `Derived`, then it can be automatically cast as a `Base&` because any instance of `Derived` is also an instance of `Base`. This is inheritance.

Now, when it comes to pointer to member-functions, the relation is actually reversed. It will seem obvious that any method of `Base` exists for an instance of `Derived` but the reverse is not true. After all the whole point of deriving is to add new functionality more often that note.

Another way of visualizing this is to use free-functions. `this` is just an implicit parameter in regular function, if we make it explicit we get:

```
void Base@call_it(Base& self);

void Derived@a_method(Derived& self);
```

Now, if I have two instances `d` of type `Derived` and `b` of type `Base` then:

- `Base@call_it(d)` makes sense
- `Derived@a_method(b)` is a compilation error

The latter could be `Derived@a_method(dynamic_cast<Derived&>(b))`, but this introduces a runtime check to actually verify the property. Statically it is not decidable.