# c++ template and inheritance with method pointer

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, function-pointers, member-pointers

if I declare:

```
class Avoidance : public Schema<std_msgs::String,prog1::Command>{
```

and I try to

```
    void*(Schema<std_msgs::String,prog1::Command>::*pt)();
    pt=&Avoidance::frontBusy;
```

compiler report me

```
error: cannot convert ‘void* (Avoidance::*)()’ 
to 
‘void* (Schema<std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >, prog1::Command_<std::allocator<void> > >::*)()’ in assignment
```

why? Avoidance inherits from

```
  Schema<std_msgs::String,prog1::Command>
```

then Avoidance IS Schema<.....>

Comment: Your answer is given here: [why can't I cast a pointer to Derived class member function to the same but of class Base](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162823/why-cant-i-cast-a-pointer-to-derived-class-member-function-to-the-same-but-of-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rid of templates to simplify, suppose you have

```
class B {
public:
    void f();
};

class D : public B {
public:
    void g();
};
```

It might seem a little backwards at first, but you can cast `void (B::*)()` to `void (D::*)()`, but you cannot cast `void (D::*)()` to `void (B::*)()`.  This makes sense when you think about how they would later be used.

```
void test() {
    void (D::*p)() = &B::f; // OK!
    void (B::*q)() = &D::g; // ERROR!

    B b;
    D d;

    (d.*p)(); // Calls B::f on `d`.  Okay, `B::f` is an inherited member.
    (b.*q)(); // Calls D::g on `b`?? But that's not a member of `b` at all!
}
```

Comment: // Calls D::g on `b`?? But that's not a member of `b` at all!
ok, but there is the same problem in general casting; if I cast a inerhitance class to a base class I know I can't access to member of class present that aren't declared in base class, it's a common rule; why in function pointer don't do simply the same?

Comment: The rules I described are for implicit casts.  Explicit casts are more generous and more dangerous.  Just like you can implicitly cast `D*` to `B*`, but you can only convert `B*` to `D*` with an explicit cast.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how member function pointers work. If `frontBusy` is a base function, you need to type the pointer appropriately. The *dispatch* will still work as expected, though!

Here's a basic example:

```
struct A { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct B : A { virtual void f() { } };

void dispatch(void (A::*pf)(), A & a)
{            //    ^^^^^
  (a.*pf)();
}

int main()
{
  B x;
  dispatch(&A::f, x);  // calls x.B::f()
}  //      ^^^^^
```

So, in your case you want:

```
void (Schema<std_msgs::String,prog1::Command>::*p)()
                        = &Schema<std_msgs::String,prog1::Command>::frontBusy;
```