# cast a pointer to member function in derived class to a pointer to abstract member function

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to do something that *seems* like it should be fairly common but I've been unable to find anyone discussing it.  [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162823/why-cant-i-cast-a-pointer-to-derived-class-member-function-to-the-same-but-of-c) is similar to what I'm trying to do, but not quite the same.

I have an abstract base class:

```
#ifndef _ABASECLASS_H_
#define _ABASECLASS_H_

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

#define CALL_MBR_FUNC(object, ptr_to_mem_func) ((object).*(ptr_to_mem_func))

class aBaseClass
{
public:

  typedef void (aBaseClass::*aBaseClass_mem_func)();

  int A;
  int B;

  aBaseClass();

  aBaseClass(int a, int b);

  virtual void function1(aBaseClass_mem_func infunc) = 0; 

  virtual void function2() = 0; 

};

#endif /* _ACLASS_H_ */
```

and I have a derived class:

```
#ifndef _ASUBCLASS_H_
#define _ASUBCLASS_H_

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include "aBaseClass.h"


/* A simple class containing two ints and some functions to demonstrate passing via various methods.  It is a subclass of aClass*/
class aSubClass: public aBaseClass
{
public:

  aSubClass();

  aSubClass(int a, int b);

  void function1(aBaseClass_mem_func infunc); 

  void function2(void); 

};

#endif /* _ASUBCLASS_H_ */
```

where function1 and function2 are:

```
void aSubClass::function1(aBaseClass_mem_func infunc) 
{
  CALL_MBR_FUNC(*this, infunc)();
}


void aSubClass::function2(void) 
{
  A = 42;
  B = 66;
}
```

Finally, in the `main()` I try to call `function1` targeted on an object of type `aSubClass`, passing a pointer to `function2` in `aSubClass`:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  aSubClass eh(2,5);
// This doesn't work    
  aBaseClass_mem_func trythis = &aSubClass::function2;
// This also doesn't work
  eh.function1(&aSubClass::function2);

  return(0);
}
```

OK, we can automatically cast a pointer-to-derived type to a pointer-to-base type.  I have now read that we can't pass a pointer-to-derived-member-function to a pointer-to-base-member-function.  I think I understand why (the derived member function might make use of things that exist in the derived class but don't exist in the base class).

But I'm trying to build a library of two categories of classes (derived from two base classes).  Call them baseclass1 and baseclass2.  One of the member functions in any derived class from baseclass1 needs to be able to be handed a particular member function from any derived class from baseclass2.  Is there some trick I can use to carry out the necessary cast?  Do I have to use the `explicit` keyword and define the cast somehow?

Comment: This isn't even close to a minimal, complete, or verifiable example. For one thing, you're `using namespace std;` comes *before* your `#include`s. And your initial "this doesn't work" doesn't work because `aBaseClass_mem_func` isn't in scope and you have to qualify it with `aBaseClass::`.

Comment: @Barry, I personally think the question conveyed the problem he was trying to solve clearly. It took a sec to figure out some of the weird symbols, which I assume are either things in some library or shortcuts to make it more readable here and not flood us with details. His question isn't "where is syntax error" (which necessitates an example), it's "why does C++ not allow this?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could shorten this example a lot:

```
struct B {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct D : B {
    void foo() override { }
};

int main() {
    void (B::*ptr)() = &D::foo; // error: cannot initialize a variable of
                                // type 'void (B::*)()' with an rvalue of type 
                                // 'void (D::*)()': different classes ('B' vs 'D')
}
```

The error message, at least on clang, is pretty clear. gcc just says cannot initialize. The issue is just that you cannot *implicitly* convert a pointer-to-derived-member to a pointer-to-base-member. But you can do it *explicitly* with `static_cast`:

```
void (B::*ptr)() = 
    static_cast<void (B::*)()>(&D::foo); // ok!
```

Side-note: please remove the `CALL_MBR_FUNC` macro from your code and never write such a thing ever again.

Comment: Thanks @Barry.  That looks very helpful, but I don't fully understand yet.  The static cast you've written is a replacement for the only line of your main(), correct?  So that is just making the cast, and I could now pass that pointer in a function that expected a pointer to a B member function, right?

Comment: @gleedadswell You can [explicitly] cast `&D::foo` to be a pointer to member function of `B`, at which point you can use it any other way you would use such a pointer.

Comment: Note that "explicitly" casting doesn't use the `explicit` keyword (which applies to constructors), it is merely a human term for things like `static_cast<...>`, `const_cast<...>`, and `reinterpret_cast<...>`

Comment: Thanks again @Barry.  That really is extremely helpful (namely, it works...).  It looks like I'd better go read about the syntax of static cast so I'll understand it more fully. 

Also, sorry about the length of my examples (I'm still having a bit of trouble deciding what is truly necessary in such an example) and also sorry about the `CALL_MBR_FUNC`: I learned to pass non-static member functions from (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) and I've never figured out another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

### Why it doesn't work:

One way you can think of a member function is this:

```
struct Foo {
    void go () { }
} ;
```

Could also be expressed as:

```
void go ( Foo* this ) { }
```

So, this:

```
typedef void(Foo::*MemberFunctionPtr)() ;
```

Is kind of like this:

```
typedef void(*MemberFunctionPtrForFoo)(Foo*) ;
```

However, if you have a subclass like this:

```
struct Bar : public Foo {
    void go2 () { }
} ;
```

That function is also kind of like this:

```
void go2 ( Bar* this ) { }
```

So when you take the address of `Bar::go2`, you're getting basically a pointer to a function that looks like `void go2 ( Bar* this )`. Why is this a problem?

Well let's look at what this means...

If you had this function:

```
void function ( Foo * this ) ;
```

And you were to do this:

```
Bar * bar = new Bar () ;
function ( bar ) ;
```

This would work (as it should). C++ kindly made it possible for you then to be able to do things like this:

```
void(*functionPtr)(Bar*) = &Foo::go ;
```

However, lets say you instead had this function:

```
void function ( Bar * this ) ;
```

And you did this:

```
Foo * foo = new Foo() ;
function ( foo ) ;
```

This wouldn't work because `foo` isn't [necessarily] a `Bar`. You could `static_cast` that, which is your way of telling the compiler "no, really, I'm pretty sure I know what I'm doing" (as opposed to `reinterpret_cast`, which is your way of telling the compiler "you're stupid; I know what I'm doing.")

Therefore, it also won't let you cast the member functions.

Another answer said that `static_cast` can convert the member functions, but that's only because `static_cast` is allowed to do the reverse of implicit cast (except for cv-qualification). You can do it, but it has the same caveats.

*Disclaimer: this is a fairly simplified version of the spec, but it gets the point across.*

### A better solution in most cases:

On to a [potentially] better solution [unless absolute performance is key]: `boost::function` (or, as of C++11 `std::function`). This is a "functor".

Your member function could instead be written:

```
class Foo {
    void function ( boost::function<void()> function ) { }
} ;
```

The functor object can be constructed with anything that can be called with the specified prototype (in this case, something taking no arguments and returning `void`). You can pass the address of a C-function for instance.

Another thing you can do is "bind" functions (which basically grabs arguments and makes a function). There's `boost::bind` for this.

For example you could do this:

```
Foo foo ;
Bar bar ;
foo.function ( boost::bind(&Bar::go2,&bar) ) ;
```

The boost bind takes some function as the first argument. If the function is a member function, the next argument must either be an instance of a class that the specified method can be called on (in which case it's copied) or a pointer to a class the specified method can be called on (in which case it's referenced). This example would actually cause the `foo` instance to call the `bar` instance (instead of itself), but you could pass `&foo` instead.

You can even be more creative:

```
class Foo {
    void function ( boost::function<void(int)> function ) {
        function ( 1 ) ;
    }
    void go2 ( int a , int b ) {
        cout << a << " " << b << endl ;
    }
} ;
Foo foo ;
foo.function ( boost::bind(&Foo::go2,&foo,_1,2) ) ;
```

That bind grabs:

- The member-function-pointer for `Foo::go2`
- A reference (or, 'pointer') to that instance of `foo`
- A placeholder for "the first argument of the resultant function," which'll become the first argument in the call to `go2`
- The number 2, which'll become the second argument in the call to `go2`

This is what'll be printed to the console:

```
1 2
```

This is an extraordinarily powerful tool and will lead you into the fantastic world of functional programming while making your life easier along the way. (It'll also make people like @CortAmmon hate you.)

Comment: It's `boost::bind` is now in the standard as `std::bind`, although I practically never use it because of lambdas.

Comment: Readability, young padawan! Readability! ;)

Comment: Thanks iAdjunct.  I think I have some reading, and some playing with code, to do before I will really be able to under all of that.  But I think you've pointed me at a whole new world within C++ that I was unaware of.