# Store Pointer to Derived Class Function in Base Class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, member

I want to create a method `schedule_function` which saves a pointer to a member function of a `BasicAlgo` object into a `ScheduledEvent`, but not have said function defined in `BasicAlgo`'s parent class, `Strategy`. Right now I am using this method which works fine for saving functions in `Strategy` but will not work for `BasicAlgo` functions:

```
class Strategy {

schedule_function(void (Strategy::*func)()) {
    // Puts the scheduled event built with the strategy function onto a list
    heap_eventlist.emplace_back(std::make_unique<events::ScheduledEvent>(func));
}}
```

I tried replacing `Strategy::*func` with `Strategy*::*func` but that caused compiler errors and it doesn't seem correct.

Is there any way to have a pointer to a member function from derived class `BaseAlgo` as a parameter **in** the base class, `Strategy`, without defining the function in `Strategy`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I cast a pointer to Derived class member function to the same but of class Base?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10162823/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way you can store a member function of `BaseAlgo` in a pointer to member function of `Strategy`.

You *can* store a member function of `BaseAlgo` in a pointer to member function of `BaseAlgo`, and you can use such pointer type with CRTP:

```
template<class T>
struct Strategy {
    void schedule_function(void (T::*func)());
};

struct BasicAlgo : Strategy<BasicAlgo> {
    void memfun();
};

int main() {
    BasicAlgo b;
    b.schedule_function(&BasicAlgo::memfun);
}
```

---

Otherwise, you could use a type-erasing function wrapper such as `std::function` instead of a function pointer.

Comment: This looks very promising––however, in the implementation (.cpp file) of schedule_function it doesn't allow me to change the parameter to `void (T::*func)()`. Do I keep it the same way using `void (Strategy::*func)()` while using `void (T::*func)()` in the header declaration?

Comment: @EvanKirkiles If you want to use a template in more than one translation unit, you'll need to put the function definitions into the header.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to store a derived class function pointer in a base class function pointer.

An alternative is to store a function with a `Strategy*` argument:

```
class Strategy {
    ...
    void schedule_function(function<void(Strategy*)> func) {
        heap_eventlist.emplace_back(std::make_unique<ScheduledEvent>(func));
    }
};
```

You can then simply use directly a member function of Strategy:

```
BasicAlgo g;
g.schedule_function (&BasicAlgo::f);   // f is a member function of Strategy
```

But you can also provide any other function that accepts a Strategy pointer as argument.  If your Strategy is a polymorphic class, you can then attempt to safely downcast the `Strategy` pointer and call a member function of the derived class.

```
g.schedule_function ([](Strategy *x)->void {
                       BasicAlgo*b=dynamic_cast<BasicAlgo*>(x); 
                       if (b) b->ff(); 
                    });
```

Here a [demo](https://ideone.com/7dwNdV).

Comment: +1 for great solution as well! However, I'm trying to keep the schedule_function easy to implement for others though and these lambdas are a bit more complex to use than user207's answer.